# What are the option for a post-hoc test after running a multinomial model?

Tags: r, regression, multinomial-distribution, post-hoc, contrasts

Currently, I am trying to run the multinomial model Age = Gender to investigate the effect of Gender on the probability that my study animal belongs to a particular age class. I am not necessarily interested in the model parameters, but more in the model fit estimates. More precise I am interested in whether:

Estimates significantly differ from 0.25 (no bias towards a particular age class)
Estimates significantly differ between males and females.
Until now, I tried to answer these questions by running the model, calculating the emmeans and using the contrast function to see if there are differences between both genders.

My main question is: Is this a statistically correct way (I know it from "normal" linear modelling , but as I use multinomial models, I don't know whether this is a good way )

**WHAT I TRIED**

```
a <- multinom(`Age class` ~ Sex , data = goodyears_hunting) 
emmeans = emmeans(a,~ `Age class`  | Sex, mode = "prob") 
x = as.data.frame(emmeans) 
gt(x, rownames_to_stub = TRUE) 
z =contrast(emmeans, "pairwise",  simple = "each", combine = TRUE, adjust = "mvt")
z = as.data.frame(z) 
gt(z, rownames_to_stub = TRUE)
```

This resulted in the following emmeans output

```
Age Sex        prob         SE      df  lower.CL    upper.CL
0   female  0.2198662   0.01383598  6   0.1860108   0.2537216
1   female  0.3169641   0.01554436  6   0.2789284   0.3549998
2   female  0.1439735   0.01172819  6   0.1152757   0.1726714
3+  female  0.3191962   0.01557349  6   0.2810892   0.3573031
0   male    0.2067437   0.01206316  6   0.1772262   0.2362612
1   male    0.2954747   0.01359085  6   0.2622191   0.3287303
2   male    0.2413486   0.01274622  6   0.2101597   0.2725375
3+  male    0.2564329   0.01300724  6   0.2246054   0.2882605
```

For example: **May I conclude that 2y female's are underrepresented in the population as 0.25 is not part from the confidence interval?**

In case for the contrasts I get the following results (selected only the relevant part)

```
Age    contrast      estimate    SE         df  t.ratio       p.value
0   female - male   0.013122464 0.01835631  6   0.71487502  0.982821954
1   female - male   0.021489382 0.02064796  6   1.04075092  0.911929460
2   female - male   -0.097375074 0.01732099  6   -5.62179680 0.010827774**
3+  female - male   0.062763228 0.02029093  6   3.09316739  0.140517335
```

**Is it correct to conclude that the ratio of 2y old indivduals is signficant different between males and females?**

I am mainly confused as I have little experience with discrete data and have not used these types of models much. Hopefully some of you can approve my way of thinking, or help me on the right way :D

Comment: How biologically plausible in the null hypothesis that the four age groups (0yo, 1yo, 2yo and 3+yo) are equal in size?

Comment: rather unlikely

Comment: That's what I thought too but wasn't sure I understand how the null is specified. So why test and reject a null hypothesis that you know is wrong? There is little knowledge to gain from this. See for example [1](https://www.fharrell.com/post/nhst-never/), [2](https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2016/02/04/the-notorious-n-h-s-t-presents-mo-p-values-mo-problems/).

Answer (score 1):

If you truly want to test the proportions against 0.25, that is possible; you should do

```
# as you have...
emmeans = emmeans(a,~ `Age class`  | Sex, mode = "prob")

test(emmeans, null = 0.25)
```

That said, I think I like your contrast comparisons better, because (a) that is a more conventional approach, and (b) when you test females against 0.25 and males against 0.25, you have two tests instead of one; what will you say if the conclusions are different?

Comment: Hi                                                                                                                                         Thanks for the answer. I am actually interested if the prob to be in a certain age class differs from 0.25. So I thinks it works with your piece of code. I use the contrast to more quantify the difference (if there is some) between two classes.          Does this clarifies my question a bit?